# Calculate the calories of the foods in a shopping list

Tags: python

So I want to create a little shopping list that calculates the total calories of the foods in the shopping list. My output should be something like this

```
apple - 78kcal
bread - 334kcal
butter - 100kcal
total calories = 512kcal
```

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

shopping = []

while True:
    print('Enter the food item ' + str(len(shopping) + 1) +
      ' (Or enter nothing to stop.):')
    name = input()
    if name == '':
        break
    shopping = shopping + [name] 
print('The food is :')
for name in shopping:
    print('  ' + name)
```

My output:

```
apple - 78kcal
bread - 334kcal
butter - 100kcal
```

My problem:
everything works well except I don't know how to add up these calories.

Comment: I can't see how that is the output. What is the input you pass?

Answer (score 0):

```
apple = '78kcal'
bread = '334kcal'
butter = '100kcal'

apple = int(apple.split('kcal')[0])
bread = int(bread.split('kcal')[0])
butter = int(butter.split('kcal')[0])

total = apple + bread + butter
total = str(total) + 'kcal'
# '512kcal'
```